# MYSQL - 2 contraints from the same column

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follow

[image]

My question is sometimes an address can have 2 or 3 different zones.

My column "zone (TINYINT)" is linked to an other table "db_zone" with a foreign key constraint

Is it possible to add a second parameter to my column like

[image]

I know I could change my column to varchar, and remove my constraint then add like "Zone: 1/2" and explode the value of my column "zone" to do my query later, but I want to keep my constraint.

I don't want either to duplicate my entry as the column "id" is also linked from an other table so I will have the same problem later.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Normalize your data and create a new table which maps addresses to zones.  There, a given address might have more than one zone record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, this is a case of a many-to-many relationship. Your address can belong to many zones and the zones can have many addresses under it.
The proper way to do this should be to make an associative table between your address and zone table(i.e. address_zone) where address_zone table has a foreign key to both the address and the zone table.

Here is a reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)

Comment: Yes I have a table db_zone witch list all the zones, 
And a table address_details which I posted
I can only have one unique address (link to a user), but this address can have many zone
If 2 users leave at the same place they have the same address ID
What do you mean by associative table ? Do I need to create a new table "address_zone" which link to my "address_details" table and my "db_zone" table ? So from my "address_details" table I will delete my column zone and address and create a new column address_zone ? But in "address_zone" table I will still link to only one zone ??

Comment: Yes, the associative table is a new table that will map an address to a zone. You don't have to delete the address column in the address_details, just delete the zone column and it will suffice. Your address_zone table can have these columns: id, address_id, zone_id. address_id is a foreign key to your address_details and zone_id to your db_zone.

Comment: Make sure that your address_id and zone_id is compoundly unique in this case which means that there cannot have 2 rows with same address_id and zone_id.
Example:
Not OK:
1, 1, 1;
2, 1, 1;

OK:
1, 1, 1;
2, 1, 2;
3, 2, 1;

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand your question
But hope this helps
You can design a relation like this :
[image]

This is an example of data input :
[image]